# How do you stop displaying next.js components on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I have a website made using next.js, and in index.js, it has a div containing the main items on the website.

```js
class Page extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <NavBar/> 
        <HeaderImage/>
        <WhatsNew/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here, it has the navbar, header, then a what's new section.
The navbar goes on top of the header as expected, but then WhatsNew goes under everything else, so isn't displaying.

It renders for a small amount of time before the image goes on top of it.

How can I make the elements in index.js all stack, so it only shows the next element under the previous?

Comment: this has noting got to do with react or next.js, just css. Show your css for all your components.

Comment: the components all have css and shouldn't be on top of each other

Comment: depends on your styles.container, and whether your components have css e.g. position:'absolute'. Inspect in the browser, and check the elements. If you don't share the css then we cannot help you, sorry you are on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer but I may have found one.

If you are using next/image, you should be able to get items to render above it by altering their z-index in your css.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the next js Image component you have to define the height first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).